# PHP - Socket connection - Send commands to a server from an input form

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to a server using php socket. I'm using the following php code which works fine:

```
<?php
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$host = "192.168.1.2";
$port=15000;

settype($buffer,"string");

//$buffer="0 MAIN VERSION\0"; 

$len= strlen($buffer);

socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);
socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);


echo( socket_read($sock, 65535) );

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

I want to create a form and input the $buffer variable from that form and then process it.
The problem is that the socket connection does not get connected nor I receive any error. 
Here is the form code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST CMD</title>

<form action="send_cmd.php" method="POST" >

COMMAND:<input type="text" name="cmd" size="70">

<input type="submit" value="send cmd">

</form> 
</head>
```

And here is the send_cmd.php:

```
<?php

settype($buffer,"string");

$buffer= $_POST["cmd"];

$len= strlen($buffer);

ECHO $buffer;
ECHO $len;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die('ERROR');
$host = "192.168.1.2";
$port=15000;
socket_connect($sock, $host, $port) or die('ERROR');;
socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);

echo $buffer;
echo( "ANSWER: <P>".socket_read($sock, 65535) );

socket_close($sock); 
?>
```

What is the problem? Should be working but it doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: `Should be working but it doesn't` - doesn't print anything, not even the ´ECHO $buffer` part, or what?

Comment: ECHO $buffer prints ok but then the socket doesn't do anything. No error nothing. If i replace the $buffer content with a manual written string then it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:

Maybe a bit more debug output can shed some light on the problem:
What does

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL); // for debugging purposes only
$buffer= $_POST['cmd'];
echo '<pre>buffer: '; var_dump($buffer); echo "</pre>\r\n"; flush();

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die('ERROR');
$host = "192.168.1.2";
$port=15000;
socket_connect($sock, $host, $port) or die('ERROR');
$cb = socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);
echo '<pre>#sent: '; var_dump($cb); echo "</pre>\r\n"; flush();

$response = socket_read($sock, 65535);
echo '<pre>response'; var_dump($response); echo "</pre>\r\n"; flush();
```

print?

Comment: Thanks for tying to help.I get waiting for localhost in my browser

Comment: Oh, sounds like a blocking socket_read .... I've put some flush()s in the code and linebreaks after the `</pre>`s - maybe, just maybe the browser will show you the partial results now, so you can at least check the the number of bytes sent and also check whether the number bytes of the input string matches the number of characters (you expect)

Comment: I really apreciate the time and effort. After each echo I get the expected result but the last echo with the read_socket created the infinite wait.

Comment: `//$buffer="0 MAIN VERSION\0";` - _exactly_ what is the output of `var_dump($buffer);` right now when you test the script (and socket_read hangs)? Your test string is zero-terminated - not the character `0` but a byte of the value zero. And the server probably uses that zero-byte to detect the end of a command/message.

Comment: I managed to solve it thank to you VolterK. I've defined the buffer like this: $buffer= "0 ".$_POST['cmd']."\0"; Thank you verry much for helping me out! Have a nice weekend!